# uint32_t pointer causes hardfault error in STM32L053 . How to align this 32 bit pointer?

Tags: c, gcc, stm32, memory-alignment

I have a 32 bit pointer which saves a password passed through a function and this password is used to compare to the saved password that I have.

```
uint32_t * password;

#define PASSWORDC 0x3f44d112

void pass_Init(uint32_t * pass) //pass is the address of 32 bit password being passed
{
    password= pass; //no issues here
}

uint16_t PasswordEnter(void)
{
    return (*password== PASSWORDC); //causes hardfault error due to alignment issues
}

void wipe(void){
    *password= 0; //causes hardfault error due to alignment issues
}
```

As I have added in comments, that the assignment of value works, in fact while debugging, I see that in `void pass_Init(uint32_t * pass)` the password gets the correct value to be assigned to it.

The issue happens if I do the comparison or any other operation which has `*password = <something>` line to it. So it definitely seems to be an issue with alignment.

Please let me know how could I solve this.

I know I can use something like `__attribute__((packed, aligned(4)))` , but I'm not sure how exactly to use it.

My code always calls the void pass_Init(uint32_t * pass) //pass is the address of 32 bit password being passed { password= pass; //no issues here } before doing any comparisons or assignments for that pointer. Even if I initialize my pointer as uint32_t * password = 0; I still get the hardfault error while comparing (although debugger shows *password has the correct value just before debugging)
As far as I see, this seems like a problem where there is unaligned access to my uint32_t * pointer

Comment: how do you call `pass_Init`?

Comment: It sounds like the address you're passing to `pass_Init()` has become invalid since you called it. This could happen if you pass a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: It could be that this is dereferencing a null pointer:  `*password== PASSWORDC`  (which would invoke undefined behavior)  i.e. password is a pointer, and if it was set to `NULL`  before calling this function.   What is the value of   `pass`  in this assignment?:  `password= pass;`

Comment: The pass_Init is called as pass_Init (&(UserPassword));
Where user password is a uint32_t password provided by the user.

As mentioned the password= pass; line assigns the correct value to *password,
Also while debugging
if I check the value of * password in 
uint16_t PasswordEnter(void)
{
    return (*password== PASSWORDC); //causes hardfault error due to alignment issues
},

the *paswword value is still correct, but just wehn I step into *password== PASSWORDC, a hardfault error occurs,

Comment: This occurs while using any other uint32_t * pointer, 
If I perform any operation on the *pointer such as assingment, comparision etc, I get a hardfault error.

This doesn't happen for the address pointer but only when I access the value *pointer

Comment: You can't just "align a pointer", you have to allocate the underlying memory storing the password so that it is aligned properly.  Please show us exactly how that memory is allocated (i.e. how exactly does your program get the address that it passes to `pass_Init`).  Also, I suspect you could reduce this down to a two-line [mcve] if you tried.  Your code probably is something like `uint8_t buffer[4]; *(uint32_t *)buffer = 0;` when you simplify it.  Showing us a minimal example like this would immediately reveal the problem.  P.S. Maybe you should just use a `uint32_t` instead of pointers.

Comment: *I know I can use something like `__attribute__((packed, aligned(4)))`*  Now **that** has a nasty code smell.  You wouldn't be doing something like [de]serializing data in a `char` buffer by overlaying it with a `packed` structure, now would you?  If you are, you're learning now why that's a really bad idea.  Because when you keep saying you "need to align the pointer" while claiming the pointer is actually referring to a `uint32_t` makes me wonder what is so broken that the value **isn't** properly aligned to begin with.  You need to post a **complete** example.

Comment: Nothing about this suggests alignment is the issue.  Everything suggests an initialised or invalid pointer.  You have provided a list of functions, but none of the code that calls them.  How they are called, in what order and with what parameters is where the issue is, not in the code show.  Code that is not called won't cause a hard fault.  Moreover by default, all specific  exceptions are disabled, and everything is a hard fault.  Enabling the specific exceptions provides better diagnostics.

Comment: Checking for NULL before dereferencing is probably a good idea.

Comment: You can inspect the pointer value in the debugger to see that it is properly aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Dereferencing a `null` or *uninitialized* pointer will invoke undefined behavior.  There are several scenarios where this could happen in the code you have shown.  Note that:

```
uint32_t * password;//creates an uninitialized pointer
```

At any point beyond the declaration of this pointer, the expression `*password` is an `int`, and more importantly indicates the pointer `password`, is being dereferenced.   So, depending on whether password is null (or initialized) at this point, it could be dereferencing a `null` (or uninitialized) pointer.   At that point, a seg-fault could occur.

```
uint16_t PasswordEnter(void)
{
    return (*password== PASSWORDC); //causes hardfault error due to alignment issues
}

//exact same thing here:

void wipe(void){
    *password= 0; //causes hardfault error due to alignment issues
}
```

Comment: My code always calls the 
void pass_Init(uint32_t * pass) //pass is the address of 32 bit password being passed
{
    password= pass; //no issues here
}

before doing any comparisons or assignments for that pointer.

Even if I initialize my pointer as 
uint32_t * password = 0; 

I still get the hardfault error while comparing (although debugger shows *password has the correct value just before debugging)

Could you let me know what else could be going wrong.? As far as I see, this seems like a problem where there is unaligned access to my uint32_t * pointer

Comment: @user9795887 - Okay - Probably should put this information into your post content.   Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413488/how-to-set-a-pointer-to-zeroth-location) dealing with assignments to pointer variables, the right and wrong ways.

Comment: @user9795887 For anyone to figure that out, you have to show where/how the actual data your pointer points to is stored . The pointer itself can't be unaligned when you have declared it like your show, it's the value you store in that pointer that would be unaligned. If you think the data your pointer points to is not properly aligned, can do `uint32_t p; memcpy(&p, password,  sizeof p);` , and use `p`  instead of `*password` . However if you have a debugger attached, you can just look at the address stored in your pointer to determine if it's aligned or not.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that you have a problem with having one too many levels of indirection everywhere.

If the password is 32 bits and you want to store it in a global variable then store it in a global uint32_t, not a global uint32_t pointer.

Change the declaration of password from:

```
uint32_t * password;
```

to:

```
uint32_t password;
```

Now change the declaration of pass_Init:

```
void pass_Init(uint32_t pass)
{
  password = pass;
}
```

And your other functions as follows:

```
bool PasswordEnter(void)
{
  return (password == PASSWORDC);
}

void wipe(void)
{
   password = 0;
}
```

Change the calling code (provided in comments) from:

```
pass_Init (&(UserPassword));
```

to

```
pass_Init (UserPassword);
```

Doing in this way results in simpler code at every line.